# XSL write second regex using output of first regex and overwrite substring with ancestor of second regex's hit

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML like this:

```
<c hw="A">
  <e hw="aardvark">
    <d t="see &lt;a onclick=&quot;goToEntryWithId('2319')&quot;&gt;mammals&lt;/a&gt; for more details."/>
  </e>
</c>
```

With, elswhere in XML:

```
<c hw="M">
  <e hw="mammals" i="2319">
    <d t="Here's useful info about mammals."/>
  </e>
</c>
```

I'm breaking the XML into multiple HTML files based on the  tags, and I want to change the onclick to an href with the appropriate target.

Desired output:

```
<p>See <a href="M.html#2319">mammals</a> for more details.
```

I need to somehow

1) find a match for an onclick expression containing ####,

2) take the number (####) referenced inside that onclick and find it elsewhere in the XML document where it's hiding somewhere like `<e i="####">`

3) find the ancestor::c[@hw] parent of search result in number

4) replace the onclick expression with a simple `href="[filename].html#[####]"`

5) Do this for every `onclick="goToEntryWithId('####')` occurrence within the XML, including for multiple hits on the same line.

Any ideas how I might achieve this?

Comment: I suggest you break your question into several, because you have multiple issues here, unrelated to each other. Finding a node by a given id is relatively trivial, using a **key**. So is finding its ancestor.  OTOH, processing escaped HTML code is difficult and error-prone. And where is [filename] supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said which version of XSLT and which XSLT processor you want to use but assuming you can use Saxon 9.6 HE at least you can make use of the XPath 3.0 `parse-xml-fragment` function to parse that encoded markup into nodes and then process them further on, only needing regular expressions to find and extract the `onclick` attribute.

So based on that I created a sample input

```
<root>
  <references>
    <c hw="A">
      <e hw="aardvark">
        <d t="see &lt;a onclick=&quot;goToEntryWithId('2319')&quot;&gt;mammals&lt;/a&gt; for more details."/>
      </e>
    </c>
  </references>
  <content>
    <c hw="M">
      <e hw="mammals" i="2319">
        <d t="Here's useful info about mammals."/>
      </e>
    </c>
  </content>
</root>
```

and a stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string">^goToEntryWithId\('[0-9]+'\)$</xsl:param>

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="id" match="content/c/e" use="@i"/>

<xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/references//@t"/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="references/c/e/d/@t">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml-fragment(.)/node()"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[@onclick[matches(., $pattern)]]">
  <xsl:variable name="id" select="replace(@onclick, '[^0-9]+', '')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="referenced-c" select="key('id', $id, $main-doc)/ancestor::c[@hw]"/>
  <a href="{$referenced-c/@hw}.html#{$id}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which using Saxon 9.6 HE or Saxon 9.5 EE (see http://xsltransform.net/94hvTzw) creates the output

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>see <a href="M.html#2319">mammals</a> for more details.
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```